# Program in c that reads from line and gives: the numbers of numbers in the file and the other characters

Tags: c

I am supposed to work out the following program: 
We want to write a program .c and also its algoritham, using the following directions: 
 - The program will count the number of characters of a file passed on parameter, i.e on the commandline, that will regroup these characters in two separate categories:

- The numbers [0-9];
- The other characters;

(the file is "non ending", i.e not possible to be placed in central memory in a table) 
Example:

```
>cat kisses.txt
I am very happy to get 1 good answer, or 5!
>count kisses.txt
numbers: 2
others: 41
```

What i have tried to do:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(int argc, char**argv){
FILE *fd ;

int nb=0, cpt=0;


if ((fd=fopen(argv[1], ‘r’) !=NULL){

unsigned int=c ;
while(c=fgetc(fd) !=EOF){
if (c>45 && c<= 57} 
nb++ ;
}
else {
cpt++
}
printf(‘numbers: %d\n and the other charaters are = %d, nb, cpt) ; 
fclose(fd);
return 0 ; 
}
```

(I would greatly appreciate if someone could check this code and give me the proper pseudo code for its algo)

Comment: You need to ask a specific question (which you haven't done). If your code is not working then please state its current behaviour, what you have done to debug it and what specific help you need.

Comment: The code, as presented, won't compile.

Comment: @kaylum , the question is how do I go about, counting the numbers of characters and digits[0-9] in a c program, if I should use argv[1], meaning whichever file I give on parameter, in the terminal. If I have a text file that has: "1 person is 2 important", my program should print: Numbers:2 Others: 21

Comment: `if (c>45 && c<= 57} nb++ ;` increments `nb` if `c` if one of **12** different values.  Perhasp [12 fingers](http://news.yahoo.com/cuban-man-24-proud-4-extra-fingers-toes-202739807.html)?

Comment: the reason why i used 45 to 57 was an unsuccessful attempt to use ascii code, but i guess it the digits are coded from 48-57. but john's answer/code below works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Carefully compare this with your own attempt to get an idea of where you went wrong...

```
int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    FILE *       fp;     /* calling a FILE* "fd" will confuse people */
    int          nb = 0;
    int          cpt = 0;
    int          c;

    if (argc <= 1) return 1;       /* make sure there is a filename */
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL) {
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {   /* better than numbers */
                nb++;
            } else {
                cpt++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("numbers: %d\n and the other charaters are = %d\n", nb, cpt) ; 
    fclose(fp);
    return 0; 
}
```

Also, don't be afraid of whitespace -- it makes things more readable!

Comment: Thank you John!!!!! I go to french university so sometimes the notations they use might cause confusion. Thanks!

Comment: ^ good catch, I missed that one